# gdb doesn't stop at next instruction under certain conditions

Tags: assembly, arm, gdb

When using the following code under gdb

```
.global main
main:
         push    {r0-r12,lr}
         bl      cls
         ldr     r0,=texte
a:       ldrb    r1,[r0],#1
         pop     {r0-r12,pc}

cls:     push    {r0-r2,lr}
         pop     {r0-r2,pc}

texte:  .asciz "Hello World!"
```

If I put a breakpoint at line `ldr     r0,=texte`, and then execute "next", the program doesn't stop at next instruction.It executes until the end.
But if I remove the `bl      cls` instruction, or I remove the label "a:", "next" works fine, ie it stops at "ldrb" inst.
I really don't understand why.
This code doesn't mean anything. It's just an extract from a bigger program to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sounds like broken debug (line) info. Use `nexti`/`stepi` to step instructions.

Comment: Nexti did nothing, but stepi did the trick.

Comment: Are you in Thumb mode?  Removing the label at `a:` shouldn't affect what `ni` (aka `nexti`) does, it doesn't care about symbols.  `si` is a lot simpler, it doesn't try to step *over* anything, it does just single-step instructions.